# VBA - Application.OnTime works overnight but not over weekend

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report I wish to run on Monday mornings, so the weekly reports are ready for when the office opens. The Macro runs a main report, saving different versions of it, and also opens and updates several Access databases.

I use Application.OnTime to automate this. I have been testing it for weeks and it works fine when I set it to run overnight (i.e. for the next day) but I have not been able to get it to work on Monday morning, when left from Friday afternoon.

Here is the timing code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:00:00"), "Timer"

End Sub


Sub Timer()

If Weekday(Date) = vbMonday Then
Call MainMacro
Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

I run the Application.OnTime sub and then leave the workbook open.

Thanks

Comment: is your date set correctly??

Comment: I'm not sure, the code works fine overnight. YowE3K's answer below seems like it could work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `OnTime` event has occurred, and your `Timer` subroutine has been called, and you have chosen to do nothing - that's the end.

You actually need to set a new `OnTime` event on Saturday, so it will run on Sunday, and then on Monday.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:00:00"), "Timer"
End Sub

Sub Timer()
    If Weekday(Date) = vbMonday Then
        MainMacro
    Else
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:00:00"), "Timer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. I will test it over the weekend and report back.

Comment: Er no, maybe I'm being dumb, but how else can I test if it will work 2 days ahead?

Comment: Just remembered to report back. It worked. Thanks Yow